# Carousel Mobile Images

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a carousel on my site which is working fine.I am using bootstrap 4 on my site and I am working on the optimization of my website. Google Lighthouse recommends that I use small images for rendering my carousel images when using a mobile. Currently the images are high resolution suitable for desktop and laptop screens. I want to know

1. What is the best resolution for images i should use for rendering carousel images on a mobile.
2. How do I render these small resolution images to mobile devices and skip loading these big images
   that are bigger in size.
3. Also, out of the four images, i want only the first one to be loaded and the rest of the three be
   deferred being loaded. They should be loaded after the first slide slides to the next one (after 3
   seconds) I am doing this because i am working on a 2G connection and the users here are
   also working on a 2G connection.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: this question is a facepalm https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: No question is a facepalm @johnSmith